# Deserialize json into class in C#

Tags: c#, json, class

```
json="{\n \"kind\": \"plus#person\",
    \n \"etag\": \"\\\"GjejyguyfTE/pdfBI8xyufoiuh9bOLZ8VyG_8\\\"\",
    \n \"gender\": \"male\",
    \n \"emails\": [\n  {\n   \"value\": \"example@gmail.com\",\n   \"type\": \"account\"\n  }\n ],
    \n \"objectType\": \"person\",
    \n \"id\": \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",
    \n \"displayName\": \"XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX\",
    \n \"name\": {\n  \"familyName\": \"XXXXXX\",\n  \"givenName\": \"XXXXXX\"\n },
    \n \"url\": \"https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",
    \n \"image\": {\n  \"url\": \"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUWA/AAAAAAI/AAbbbbAA/42hhscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=70\"\n },
    \n \"isPlusUser\": true,
    \n \"language\": \"en\",
    \n \"ageRange\": {\n  \"min\": 21\n },
    \n \"circledByCount\": 0,
    \n \"verified\": false\n}\n"



 public class GoogleUser
    {
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public string etag { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public Email[] emails { get; set; }
        public string objectType { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public Name name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
        public bool isPlusUser { get; set; }
        public string language { get; set; }
        public AgeRange ageRange { get; set; }
        public int circledByCount { get; set; }
        public bool verified { get; set; }
    }

    public class Name
    {
        public string familyName { get; set; }
        public string givenName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Email
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
    public class Image 
    {
        public string url { get; set; } 
    }
    public class AgeRange 
    {
        public int min { get; set; }
    }





GoogleUser  user = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<GoogleUser>(json);
```

I am developing in `C# 4.0`
I use `login with google+` button in my project.
I would like to get user's by using `access_token`.
I can get them as `json` filen.
Then I would like to copy them my `GoogleUser class`.
I don't get error, But `user` always equal `null`.
By this way, yesterday I could get user's data, but not today.

What can be my problem ?

[image: <code>string a</code> is not <code>null</code>, it is my <code>json</code> file, but <code>user</code> is <code>null</code>]

Comment: The code you posted seems to work...

Comment: First thing; browser is probably caching the request / data and screwing things up (chrome is good at screwing up javascript caching) and secondly; I would use the JsonProperty attribute for multiple reasons, e.g. [JsonProperty("kind")] and then Propercase the property.

Comment: I will try JsonProperty, but it worked yesterday by this way.

Comment: Indeed, that won't fix it, but I think it s a good practice... try completely clearing your browser cache... which browser are you using by the way?

Comment: Opera and Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: in the picture `string a` is not `null`. it is my `json` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

```
user =  new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<A>( a );
```

since you say "a" has the value in the string.  Maybe the problem is that you are calling ReadToEnd twice?

Comment: I added picture after posted my question, therefore other users couldn't see it,
Thank you very much, now it works. I added `string a` today )

Comment: For example I have `name ="Jeyhun"` `surname="Elvin"` in `json` file.
I would like to get only `name`.
Am I obliged to declare in my `USERS class` `surname` too?
or it is enough 
`USERS class { public string name {get; set;} }`

Comment: I'd say try it out.  I'm not sure.  I would think it would work.